# Does a program need to respond straight to the point or politely?

Tags: usability

I have read **"What is the recommended wording for a generic error message"** and it's helpful, but doesn't address my main question:

What should I prefer in any written programm: The polite or the straight forward way if my program is interacting with the user (e.g. giving feedback to an action or pointing out that something does not work).

---

I wonder if it's better if the program responds straight to the point or politely.

Consider the following example:
The user clicks a button to print something based on a template. However, the template does not exist.

Which feedback would you prefer:

1. **The template is not defined yet. Please make sure to set the
   template before you print it out.**
2. **Make sure to configure the template before printing.**

What is generally better?

Comment: Unless someone has someone has some real user studies to quantify this, this is an invitation to give subjective answers.  Please resist ...

Comment: You give more information in the first example, although it's still lacking (does "it" refer to the template or something else? if something else, what else?).

Comment: Most ideally, the user never gets the opportunity to select an option that doesn't exist yet. But if it's just about the message: "That template hasn't been set. Would you like to configure it now? (Y/N)"

Comment: @FabianBigler http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/someone-flagged-my-question-as-already-answered-but-its-not

Comment: @gnat thank you. I hope I made my point somehow clearer